# How do I get the timeZone from the region selected using android.icu.util

Tags: java, android, timezone

Creating 2 spinners. Parent spinner for the region, Child spinner for the time zone. I am having trouble with getting the time zones to show up for the selected region. Here is the code I used to get the regions.

```
Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        regions = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Locale loc : locale) {
            region = loc.getDisplayCountry();

            Log.e("Country",""+region);
            if (region.length() > 0 && !regions.contains(region)) {
                regions.add(region);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: " + regions);
        Collections.sort(regions, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Here is my adapter for the spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> regionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.spinner_item, regions);
        regionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        mRegion.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
```

Than I have the onSelectedItem here

```
mRegion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                timeZones = android.icu.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

                    //Time Zone Adapter
                    ArrayAdapter<String> timeZoneAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.spinner_item, timeZones);
                    timeZoneAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

                    mTimeZone.setAdapter(timeZoneAdapter);
                }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

With this set up I am able to have the dropdown spinners working but they just display all the regions and all the time zones available.

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: How is that? This is my first time posting on here.....

Comment: Write your title so that it distinguishes your Question about time zones from the [many other Questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+android+time+zone&t=ipad&ia=web) asking about time zones. What *specifically* are you asking about handling these time zone objects?

Comment: Hi.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Comment: Also note that you aren't passing any parameters to `getAvailableIDs` - so it's going to give you the entire list.  See [the ICU docs](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/TimeZone.html) for the various options.

Comment: Yes. I know there isn’t anything being passed in parameters in this question. I can type in the 2letter country code and it will display them for that region than. But what I need is for it to use the first spinners selection for that. I know I’m not greatest at explaining lol.

Comment: I was able to figure something out. I changed my code to use the 2 letter country code and than grabbed the selected item from the spinner and it worked. I just need it to display the whole name of the region instead of the 2 letter code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out my question.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void getTimeZoneByCountryCode(){
        //Retrieves the selected Region
        String _region = mRegion.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //Uses selected region for time zone!
        timeZone = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(getCountryCodeFromName(_region));

        //Time Zone Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> timeZoneAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.spinner_item, timeZone);
        timeZoneAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

        mTimeZone.setAdapter(timeZoneAdapter);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void getCountryName(){
        Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        regions = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Locale loc : locale) {
            region = loc.getDisplayCountry();

            Log.e("Country",""+region);
            if (region.length() > 0 && !regions.contains(region)) {
                regions.add(region);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: " + regions);
        Collections.sort(regions, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static String getCountryCodeFromName(String country) {
        return Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())
                .stream()
                .map((s) -> new Locale("", s))
                .filter((l) -> l.getDisplayCountry().toLowerCase().equals(country.toLowerCase()))
                .findFirst()
                .map((l) -> l.getCountry().toLowerCase())
                .orElse("UNKNOWN");
    }
```

here is the code I used to write the country name, convert country name to country code and than get the time zone from selected country.